# Reverse values of elements in list

Tags: python, list

So I got this list:

```
my_old_list = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,0)]
```

and I would like to reverse the content of the elements to:

```
my_new_list = [(2,1),(4,3),(6,5),(8,7),(0,9)]
```

I have find a lot of different things, but it never really changes the list into the way I want.

Comment: Since tuples are immutable, there is no way to reverse a tuple in-place. Creating a copy requires more space to hold all of the existing elements. Therefore, this exhausts memory.

Comment: `[(b, a) for (a, b) in my_old_list]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
[tuple(reversed(i)) for i in my_old_list]
# [(2, 1), (4, 3), (6, 5), (8, 7), (0, 9)]
```

Or similarly:

```
[(*reversed(i),) for i in my_old_list]
# [(2, 1), (4, 3), (6, 5), (8, 7), (0, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

try it :

```
my_old_list = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,0)]

for i in range(len(my_old_list)) :
    my_old_list[i] = my_old_list[i][::-1]

print(my_old_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_new_list = map(lambda tup: (tup[1], tup[0]), my_old_list)
```

Comment: better: `lambda tup: tup[::-1]` to support tuples of any length

Answer (score 0):

I would use list comprehension here as follows:

```
new_list = res = [(sub[1], sub[0]) for sub in my_old_list ]
```

Output

```
[(2, 1), (4, 3), (6, 5), (8, 7), (0, 9)]
```

Comment: better: `sub[::-1]` to support tuples of any length